# How to create a local_db.bin from a live app engine application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to export a google app engine's datastore and use it to create a local_db.bin file for use with eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

There will be more than one way to do what you want.

The sole sane way to create a `local_db.bin` file is to use a local dev web app server to do it.

If your source data resides in the Google cloud somewhere (GAE datastore or other Google Cloud storage mechanism) then you could:

- use a running GAE application to access this data and export it in a
  form suitable for your local dev web app server to read (and then
  write to its local datastore)
- somehow use your local dev web app server to read data from the Google cloud directly (if this is possible) (and then write to its local datastore)
- (?) use a non-GAE Google Cloud mechanism to export data in a form suitable to be read by your local dev web app server.

Any help?